# Circular timer sgv html js css, when making it bigger, the lines don't match up to the size

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, timer

I have a circular timer done with js, css and html using svg. When i make the timer bigger, the lines don't match up with the timer so there is always a gap in the circular timer. How do i make the line that is drawn bigger to complete a full circle?

```
HTML

        <div id="timer" style="height: 44px">
    <div class="item html">
        <h2 style="left: 0px; top: 28px">1200</h2>
        <svg width="160" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
         <g>
          <title>Layer 1</title>
          <circle id="circle" class="circle_animation" r="69.85699" cy="81" cx="81" stroke-width="8" stroke="#be1e2d" fill="none"/>
         </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
    var mins = 20;
    var seconds = mins * 60; /* how long the timer runs for */
    var initialOffset = '440';
    var i = -1200;
    var interval = setInterval(


    function() {
        $('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset-(i*(initialOffset/seconds)));
        $('h2').text(Math.abs(i));
        if (i == 0) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        i++;  
    }, 1000);
```

CSS

```
.item h2 {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 125px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    left: 31px;
    top: 24px;
    height: 98px;
}

svg {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.circle_animation {
  stroke-dasharray: 440; /* this value is the pixel circumference of the circle */
  stroke-dashoffset: 440;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

Comment: how are you making the timer bigger?

Comment: By changing the radius to make it bigger, and then the width and height of the box that the circle is drawn in. For example. I've changed the radius to 90 and now only 3/4 of a circle is drawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave the circle radius alone, add a viewBox attribute to the `<svg>` element viewBox="0 0 160 160" then you can change the svg height/width as you wish and the circle will automatically scale without changing the radius at all.

Comment: Would you also know how to change the timer so it counts down from 20:00 (mm:ss) rather than 1200 seconds? If so i would be eternally grateful!